# How to play local song file from local JSON to the app?

Tags: ios, json, swift, audio, avfoundation

I have a music app which have a table view with custom cell, which have labels and info which already in my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "loop_name" : "Come Back",
        "Instrument" :"Guitar",
        "loop_link" : "local link to wav file", (need to figure out)
        "producer" : "Bernulli"
    }
]
```

The main problem is, I don't know how to implement local audio file into JSON file and after this load this data to my app. Here is my custom cell with labels (which already in JSON file and button, which should play songs from JSON file in each of the row in table view):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol CustomSongDelegate: AnyObject {
    func btnUseTap(cell: CustomLoopsCell)
}

class CustomSongCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    weak var delegate: CustomSongDelegate?
    
    var songs: [String] = []
    
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var loopNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var producerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var instrumentLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnUse(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.btnUseTap(cell: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the JSON needs only the file name, you get the URL with `Bundle.main.url(forResource:”fileName”, withExtension:”mp3”)` or from the documents directory with `FileManager`.

Comment: @vadian so in JSON file I should write song name or what?

Comment: The name of the corresponding file on disk.

Comment: @vadian so for example: songname.wav and make it look like in json: "song_name" : "songname.wav" ???

Answer (score 1):

Get the loop local file's name from your JSON file and you may use it to play your audio like that:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer!

func playLoop(loopLocalFileName: String) {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: loopLocalFileName, withExtension: "wav") // you should check it for errors
    player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!) // of course you should catch the error and deal with it...
    player.play()
}
```

In order to parse your JSON more easily try using a struct like this:

```
struct Loop: Codable{
    var name: String
    var instrumentName: String
    var localFileName: String
    var producerName: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "loop_name"
        case instrumentName = "Instrument"
        case loopLocalFileName = "loop_link"
        case producerName = "producer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good! But loopLocalFileName, it should be codable struct or no?

Comment: A good way to handle your JSON is to create a codable struct named “Loop”, then one of your variables will be “localFileName”, If you have trouble parsing your JSON like that write it here and I’ll add it to my answer

Comment: I know how to do it, but I don't know how write it correctly for song file. If its not hard to you, maybe you can make an example from my json file which is on the top. Thank you!